# Power Bi measures work on desktop application but fail when published

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart of elapsed time. These are the measures I am using:

```
Start Time = Today() & " " & TIME(07,00,00)

End Time = Today() & " " & TIME(15,30,00)

Time Elapsed = If(((DATEDIFF([Start Time], Now(), MINUTE) / 60)) < 8.5,(DATEDIFF([Start Time], Now(), MINUTE) / 60), 8.5)

Time Left = If((DATEDIFF( Now(), [End Time], MINUTE)/60) > 0, DATEDIFF( Now(), [End Time], MINUTE)/60, 0)
```

Graphing "Time Elapsed" and "Time Left" works perfectly on the Power Bi desktop application, but when this is published to my online power bi repository, the time elapsed is 8, and the time left is 0. Any insights towards fixing this issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

When you work in Power BI Desktop, it will show times and dates (Now() and Today()) in the timezone of the local machine. When you deploy to the Power BI service it uses UTC.

Comment: Does it always use UTC in DAX? I know I've seen it use the server's timezone instead when calling analogous functions in the query editor (M language).

Comment: I believe it does always use UTC. M has time zone conversion functions to get around this where DAX doesn't. 
http://radacad.com/solving-dax-time-zone-issue-in-power-bi

Comment: I will second that the service will always use UTC.
If the report is only going to be viewed in the service, I just subtract 8 (for PST) to convert to my timezone.
If the report will be used in the service and as a pbix file, I would suggest using [`UTCNOW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/utcnow-function-dax) and [`UTCTODAY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/utctoday-function-dax) so that the service and desktop are aligned.

Comment: Subtracting 8 for PST only works for half the year though. It would be nice to have timezone conversion functions in DAX, or for the US to stop observing DST.